# C# compiler flaw?: Not detecting methods that always throw exceptions

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

Why does the MS C# compiler complain that "not all code paths return a value" in the following scenario?

```
public int Foo(bool flag)
{
    if(flag)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ThrowException(); // this method always throws an exception

        // return -1; // why do I need to add this code that will never be called?
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

It can't guess that ThrowException() is a method that always throws exceptions. For that you'd need static code analysis.

Static code analysis is available in VS 2010, but only for the more expensive versions of VS, I believe.

Comment: Absolutely right.  But to clarify the OPs point, if you change the method ThrowException() to return an Exception and change the code to: throw ThrowException(), It would behave like the OP wanted.

Comment: Well, VS 2008 does have static code analysis, otherwise it wouldn't raise this error.

Comment: @Kirk: I don't get the point of doing so. I don't even get the point of having a method always throwing an Exception. I guess this is more of a theoretical question, though.

Comment: @Christopher: When we talk of static code analysis we mean a more elaborated kind of analysis. Although it is obvious for a human that your code will always either throw something or return something, it currently isn't for the compiler.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that the premium version of VS 2010 handles this correctly?

Comment: @devoured elysium: Sometimes it can be useful to have a delegate throw an exception (e.g. a file-parsing method performs a callback if an error occurs; that callback may log the problem and/or throw an exception or do something else).  Generally, though, I think it will be more useful to have the exception thrown nearer the source of the problem.

Comment: FYI- in my case, the method is actually called ThrowWrappedException(), which is a helper method that adds more detail to the exception.

Answer (score 1):

The `else` branch does not have a `return` statement. That means that `Foo` does not return a value when entering the `else` branch.

Why don't you do:

```
public int Foo(bool flag)
{
    if (!flag) {
        ThrowException();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

BTW I always feel that validation should be done first.

Comment: Yes, I also believe this code is way more understandable. Plus it has less indentation.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all: Not all code path return a value. I reckon the purpose of `ThrowException()` is to throw an exception. If it does so, I can see how the error message would seem strange. However, consider the consequence of accepting this a valid code. If the implementation of `ThrowException()` was changed at a later point to no longer throw an exception, the code above would suddenly fail, and that would probably come as a big surprise. The compiler is picking the safe road here.